# Running OpenCV Android SDK Samples

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I have downloaded **OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk** and **android-ndk-r9c**. I followed a [tutorial by Stanford university](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Windows-API11.pdf), which tells me to import all sample projects from the OpenCV SDK directory and then everything will work magically.

Obviously, that is not the case. Below is a screenshot of one of the sample projects (and its build path) that I imported to Eclipse:
[image]

**Do you know of a valid and recent tutorial to make the OpenCV samples running?**

I checked the [tutorial on OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#android-dev-intro) but it does not describe how to get the samples running. In particular, I am confused about these:

**2)** I can see that I am missing all `android.*`  and `org.opencv.android.*` imports. Do I need to manually include these to the build paths of the projects?

**3)** Where does the Android NDK go in this process?

**4)** There is no `./jni/Andorid.mk` file in any of the projects. Do I have to manually add these?

Comment: I don't remember how I did it but I do remember that I've used google a lot while setting up NDK and after that OpenCV. I think that OpenCV tutorial you've linked to was most useful resource while setting up OpenCV. Have you already confirmed that your NDK setup is good (without trying to use OpenCV)? Can you do simple native call from java to c?

Comment: Just another thing, I remember that I also got problems with some of OpenCV example projects while trying to import them. However, by importing projects one by one I was able to get all I wanted up and running. I think that there was something wrong with eclipse importing feature, I've got similar problems with other project types also (with mass import).

Comment: You might find some useful information [here](https://coderwall.com/p/nakhrq?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Ajonasvautherin&t%5B%5D=jonasvautherin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click each sample project folder > Properties > Select Android from the left list of options:

- 1) Check if you have something for "Project Build target" (example: "Android 4.4.2").
- 2) Check if you have something in the "library" box and if it does not have a red X next to its path. If it has a red X, edit to select the correct path to where you placed the opencv library.

Also do step (1) for the Opencv Library project, if you imported it to your workspace like it is described in the installation tutorial.

Comment: Let us know if it fixed?

Comment: Hello @Rui MArques, I am having same problem.. the library box is red X but I cannot edit the path can you please help

Comment: @MMH sorry, that I do not know what it is. Maybe trying a different eclipse version helps.

Answer (score 1):

The steps explained in the [Android Development with OpenCV article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html) helped me solve the problem:

Do take caution in using outdated tutorials on the web. In my case, the Stanford university tutorial was outdated and was therefore misleading.

Look for documents dated 2012-2013 when you are dealing with OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow these steps:

- Right click on the example marked with errors ->
- Select android from the list ->
- on Project Build Target hit the checkbox ->
- then apply.

After that the error for the specific example should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try project->clean->clean all.